# Descartes product with repetition

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinatorics

So i wanted to make a function that takes positive integer **`n`** and returns bunch of **`n-tuples`**, filled with all possible combinations of `True/False (1/0)`, for example:

```
f(1) = (0,),(1,)


f(2) = (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)
```

My code was:

```
def fill(n: int) -> Tuple[Tuple[int]]:
    if n == 1:
        return (0,),(1,)
    return tuple((i + j) for i in fill(n-1) for j in fill(1))
```

I've heard python isn't very good with recursion, and generally feel this isn't effective solution.

It seemed like using powerset of a range of a given number (recipe for powerset is from the `itertools` module) and then using some kind of [Indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) would do the thing.

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def range_powerset(n: int):
    s = list(range(n))
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

def indicator(A: Iterable, B: Iterable):
    return tuple(i in A for i in B)

def fill2(n: int):
    return (indicator(i, range(n)) for i in range_powerset(n))
```

Yet it seems like too much work for a pretty basic thing.
Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Did you read https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: powerset of a given set with generators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826571/python-powerset-of-a-given-set-with-generators)

Comment: This question is probably best suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: To knelwood: what exactly is not a powerset? if you mean the name of topic, i chose it for lack of a better name, id be glad if you can suggest something else.
if you mean function i defined range_powerset, what it returns is basically a powerset, no mistake here.     
To  jonrsharpe: thanks for reminder, did i miss something there? i took powerset recipe there but it wasnt exactly a solution for my task

Comment: One more possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482308/whats-a-good-way-to-combinate-through-a-set

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you describe is not a powerset but a Descartes product with repetition. Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools
def fill(n):
    return itertools.product((0,1), repeat=n)

print(list(fill(3)))

# [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: thanks, if no one minds im renaming question accordingly