# Split python tuple in subtuples with capacity limit in functional programming style

Tags: python, functional-programming, python-itertools

I have some tuple in python.
And capacity limit, for example, is 5.
I want to split tuple in subtuples limited by sum of them elements:

For example:

```
input: (3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2) and capacity = 5
output: (3, 1) (4) (2, 2, 1) (1, 2) #each subtuple is less than 5, order safe.
```

I am looking for a nice expressive solution of this task preferable in functional style of programming (using `itertools.dropwhile` for example or something like that)

Comment: I found a way but it is ugly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could encapsulate non-functional part and call it from functional code:

```
from itertools import groupby

class GroupBySum:
    def __init__(self, maxsum):
        self.maxsum = maxsum
        self.index = 0
        self.sum = 0

    def __call__(self, value):
        self.sum += value
        if self.sum > self.maxsum:
            self.index += 1
            self.sum = value
        return self.index

# Example:

for _, l in groupby((3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2), GroupBySum(5)):
    print(list(l))
```

Comment: This one, although so "impure" it makes me shiver, is really the most readable solution here, IMO ;)

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't help it but write something close to what I'd do in Haskell (while still somewhat pythonic, I think):

```
def take_summed(xs, cap):
    if len(xs) <= 1:
        return xs, ()
    else:
        x, *rest = xs

        if x > cap:
            return (), xs
        else:
            init, tail = take_summed(rest, cap - x)
            return (x,) + tuple(init), tail

def split(xs, cap=5):
    if len(xs) <= 1:
        yield xs
    else:
        chunk, rest = take_summed(xs, cap)
        yield chunk

        if rest != ():
            yield from split(rest, cap)
```

Never hesitate to split functions into subproblems. Result:

```
In [45]: list(split((3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2), 5))
Out[45]: [(3, 1), (4,), (2, 2, 1), (1, 2)]
```

The problem with making this shorter is not that it's not doable without side effects, but that you have to carry around additional accumulated state, so even when using `reduce` you would need to invent something really complex, to pass around the sum between applications.

Comment: This is nice and straightforward, readable and 100% functional, I am surprised not to see it higher up.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a slightly different approach from that of @Jean, that slices the input tuple instead of building smaller lists with appends, and offers a little performance boost:

```
def group_by_capacity(tup, capacity=5):
    t = iter(tup)
    curr, s =  0, next(t)

    for i, v in enumerate(t, 1):
        if s + v  > capacity:
            yield tup[curr:i]
            curr  = i
            s = v
        else:
            s += v
    yield tup[curr:]
```

---

```
>>> list(group_by_capacity((3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2)))
[(3, 1), (4,), (2, 2, 1), (1, 2)]
```

Some timing:

```
In [35]: from random import randrange

In [36]: start = tuple((randrange(1,5) for _ in range(100000)))

In [37]: %%timeit
   ....: list(group_by_capacity(start))
   ....:
10 loops, best of 3: 47.4 ms per loop

In [38]: %%timeit
   ....: list(generate_tuple(start))
   ....:
10 loops, best of 3: 61.1 ms per loop
```

Comment: I'm feeling that everyone agrees that a full-functionnal programming one-liner would be really tough!

Comment: check my last edit, a functional approach. Horrible, but works.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a little surprised no one has used `itertools.accumulate` with a key function yet.  Anyway, my entry:

```
from itertools import groupby, accumulate

def sumgroup(seq, capacity):
    divided = accumulate(enumerate(seq),
                         lambda x,y: (x[0],x[1]+y[1])
                                     if x[1]+y[1] <= capacity else (x[0]+1,y[1]))
    seq_iter = iter(seq)
    grouped = groupby(divided, key=lambda x: x[0])
    return [[next(seq_iter) for _ in g] for _,g in grouped]
```

There are lots of variants, e.g. you could use `zip(seq, divided)` to avoid the `seq_iter`, etc., but this was the first way that came to mind.  It gives me

```
In [105]: seq = [3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2]

In [106]: sumgroup(seq, 5)
Out[106]: [[3, 1], [4], [2, 2, 1], [1, 2]]
```

and agrees with the `GroupBySum` result:

```
In [108]: all(sumgroup(p, 5) == [list(l) for _, l in groupby(p, GroupBySum(5))]
     ...:     for width in range(1,8) for p in product(range(1,6), repeat=width))
     ...:     
     ...: 
Out[108]: True
```

Comment: I think your code would be significantly more readable if you used named function and tuple unpacking instead of lambda

Answer (score 3):

I was waiting for the first answer to provide a slightly functional approach:

```
start = (3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2)

def generate_tuple(inp):
    current_sum = 0
    current_list = []
    for e in inp:
        if current_sum + e <= 5:
            current_list.append(e)
            current_sum += e
        else:
            if current_list:  # fixes "6" in first position empty tuple bug
                yield tuple(current_list)
            current_list = [e]
            current_sum = e
    yield tuple(current_list)

print([i for i in generate_tuple(start)])
```

result:

```
[(3, 1), (4,), (2, 2, 1), (1, 2)]
```

EDIT: I found a full functional approach using a memory effect otherwise it is not doable. It's ugly and it hurts me only when I think how I'll explain it clearly. I have spiked the input data set a little or it would have been too easy

```
start = (6, 7, 3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1 ,3, 1, 1)
```

now the code. 3 lines, get some aspirin, you'll need it as much as I did:

```
mem=[0,0]
start = start + (5,)
print([start[mem[-2]:n] for i in range(0,len(start)) for n in range(i+1,len(start)) if ((n==i+1 and start[i]>=5) or (sum(start[mem[-1]:n])<=5 and sum(start[mem[-1]:n+1])>5)) and not mem.append(n)])
```

I'll try to explain.

- I use a memory effect because it's not possible without it. Stored in `mem` and set to 0,0 at start
- since the function disregards last item, I modify input data to add threshold value to previous values are not dropped
- the only simple thing is the computation of 2 sums and detection of the index from which it exceeds the threshold. When this threshold is detected, both conditions are met and the third condition is activated: store index in `mem`. Since `append` returns `None`, the last condition is made to be always true
- That `((n==i+1 and start[i]>=5)` is to detect single values greater or equal to 5.
- The rest is some fine-tuning until the output is the same as the procedural approach which now doesn't look so bad in comparison :)

Comment: If the first item in the tuple is greater than `5` this will yield an empty tuple as the first result.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need them all in tuples, but if you don't you can just remove the `tuple(...)` casting:

```
def chunkit(tpl, capacity):
    ret = []
    cur = []
    for x in tpl:
        if sum(cur) + x > capacity:
            ret.append(tuple(cur))
            cur = [x]
        else:
            cur.append(x)
    if cur != []:
        ret.append(tuple(cur))

    return tuple(ret)
```

A few examples:

```
In [24]: chunkit((3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1), 5)
Out[24]: ((3, 1), (4,), (2, 2, 1), (1,))

In [25]: chunkit((3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, ), 5)
Out[25]: ((3, 1), (4,), (2, 2, 1))

In [26]: chunkit((3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 5), 5)
Out[26]: ((3, 1), (4,), (2, 2, 1), (5,))

In [27]: chunkit((3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 5, 6), 5)
Out[27]: ((3, 1), (4,), (2, 2, 1), (5,), (6,))

In [28]: chunkit((3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 5, 6, 1, 6), 5)
Out[28]: ((3, 1), (4,), (2, 2, 1), (5,), (6,), (1,), (6,))
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this counts as functional, but it's the closest I could think of:

```
def groupLimit(iterable, limit):
    i, cSum = 0, 0
    def pred(x):
        nonlocal i, cSum, limit
        i, cSum = (i + 1, x) if (x + cSum) > limit else (i, cSum + x)
        return i if x <= limit else -1
    return (tuple(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(iterable, pred) if k != -1)
```

This will also sort out single values greater than the limit. If that's not intended the last two lines can be changed to:

```
        return i
    return (tuple(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(iterable, pred))
```

example:

```
t = (3, 1, 6, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2)
a = groupLimit(t,5)
print(tuple(a))
# version 1 -> ((3, 1), (2, 2, 1), (1, 2))
# version 2 -> ((3, 1), (6,), (2, 2, 1), (1, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets define the [powerset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826571/python-powerset-of-a-given-set-with-generators) with `itertools`

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(lst):
    for subset in chain.from_iterable(combinations(lst, r) for r in range(len(lst)+1)):
        yield subset
```

Then we can do it in a one-liner

```
[subset for subset in powerset(input) if sum(subset)<=capacity]
```

Comment: Good idea! very readable and expressive but unfortunately it does not solve a problem beacause it's breaks order (subtuple element's must be 
neighbors) and also has 2^N time complexity

Answer (score 1):

A more general solution:

```
def groupwhile(iterable,predicate,accumulator_function):
    continue_group = False
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    try:
        accumulated = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    current_group = [accumulated]
    for item in iterator:
        continue_group = predicate(accumulated,item)
        if continue_group:
            current_group.append(item)
            accumulated = accumulator_function(accumulated,item)
        else:
            yield current_group
            accumulated = item
            current_group = [item]

    yield current_group

#your case
assert (list(groupwhile(
    (3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2),
    lambda previous_sum,item: previous_sum + item <= 5,
    lambda previous_sum,item: previous_sum + item,
))) == [[3, 1], [4], [2, 2, 1], [1, 2]]

#equivalent to groupby with key not set
assert (list(groupwhile(
    (3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2),
    lambda previous_item,item: previous_item == item,
    lambda _,item: item,
))) == [[3], [1], [4], [2, 2], [1, 1], [2]]

#break on duplicates
assert (list(groupwhile(
    (3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2),
    lambda previous_item,item: previous_item != item,
    lambda _,item: item,
))) == [[3, 1, 4, 2], [2, 1], [1, 2]]

#start new group when the number is one
assert (list(groupwhile(
    (3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2),
    lambda _,item: item != 1,
    lambda _1,_2: None,
))) == [[3], [1, 4, 2, 2], [1], [1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution, not very clean but it use just reduce:

```
# int, (int, int, ...) -> ((int, ...), ...)
def grupBySum(capacity, _tuple):

    def  _grupBySum(prev, number):
        counter = prev['counter']
        result = prev['result']
        counter = counter + (number,)
        if sum(counter) > capacity:
            result = result + (counter[:-1],)
            return {'counter': (number,), 'result': result}
        else:
            return {'counter': counter, 'result': result}

result = reduce(_grupBySum, _tuple, {'counter': (), 'result': ()}).values()
return result[1]  + (result[0],)

f = (3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2)
h = grupBySum(5, f)
print(h) # -> ((3, 1), (4,), (2, 2, 1), (1, 2))
```